# Converting 2d fixed sized array to a slice

Tags: rust

With a 1 dimensional array it is possible to convert from a fixed sized array to a slice but is this possible with 2d array in a trivial way?

```
fn foo(r: &[&[usize]]) { }
let r = [[0usize; 10]; 10];
foo(&r); //<== error expected type `&[&[usize]]` found type `&[[usize; 10]; 10]`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no trivial way of doing this (for some definition of trivial). The problem is that `&[&[usize]]` is a slice of slices (like a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)), while `[[0usize; 10]; 10]` is a 2D array. The data in a 2D array is contiguous, a line starts after the end of the previous line and all lines have the same number of elements. In a jagged array, each line can have a different length, and this length must be stored with each line (in Rust, a slice is a length and a pointer).

That said, you can change the definition of `foo` (this is the best alternative, because there is no extra allocation):

```
// a slice of T, where T can be used as &[usize]
fn foo<T>(r: &[T])
    where T: AsRef<[usize]>
{
    for line in r {
        println!("{:?}", line.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = [[0usize; 10]; 10];
    foo(&r);
}
```

or create a temporary vector of slices:

```
fn foo(r: &[&[usize]]) {
    for line in r {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = [[0usize; 10]; 10];
    let x: Vec<&[usize]> = r.iter().map(|v| v.as_ref()).collect();
    foo(&x);
}
```